# Inverse of a certain block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

So I'm trying to compute the inverse of a block matrix that's a subset of a larger consideration I was attempting (this particular matrix comes from the normal and orthogonal equations for least squares). Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with full column rank, and I'm trying to compute the inverse of this guy:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
A^* & A^*A\\
I+AA^* & A
\end{bmatrix}$$
Following through straightforward Gaussian elimination and augmenting by the identity, I right multiply $A^*$ with its right inverse (which exists since it has full row rank), and then I zero out the bottom left corner by $\text{new_row}_2=-(I+AA^*)\text{row}_1+\text{row}_2$.
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
A^*    & A^*A   & I & 0\\
I+AA^* & A      & 0 & I
\end{array}\right]
\to
\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
I    & A^*A(A^*)^{-1}   & (A^*)^{-1} & 0\\
0 & -(I+AA^*)A^*A(A^*)^{-1}+A      & -(I+AA^*)(A^*)^{-1} & I
\end{array}\right]$$
However, here's where I'm stuck. The bottom-right entry is far too convoluted for me to find an inverse and get an identity matrix out of. Also, the $A^*)A^*$ part of the term doesn't even make any sense, as this is multiplying $n\times m$ with $n\times m$ (and likely true for the $A(A^*)^{-1}$ as well). I assume I can't just right-multiply like that and follow through. Is there a way to simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
A^\ast & A^\ast A\\
I_m+AA^\ast & A
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
&=
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
A^\ast A&A^\ast\\
A&I_m+AA^\ast
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&I_n\\
I_m&0
\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&I_m\\
I_n&0
\end{bmatrix}
\color{red}{\begin{bmatrix}
A^\ast A&A^\ast\\
A&I_m+AA^\ast
\end{bmatrix}}^{-1}.
\end{align*}
Since both $A^\ast A$ and the [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) $S=I_m + AA^\ast - A(A^\ast A)^{-1}A^\ast$ are invertible, you can compute the inverse on the last line by the matrix inversion formula
$$
\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\ C&D\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
= \begin{bmatrix}A^{-1}+A^{-1}BS^{-1}CA^{-1} & -A^{-1}BS^{-1}\\ -S^{-1}CA^{-1} & S^{-1} \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $S=D-CA^{-1}B$ (to apply this formula, you should replace $A$ by $A^\ast A$ and $B$ by $A^\ast$ etc.).

Alternatively, if you perform a singular value decomposition $A=U_{m\times m}\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_{n\times n}\\ 0_{(m-n)\times n}\end{bmatrix}V_{n\times n}^\ast$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary, it is easy to see that
$$
\color{red}{\begin{bmatrix}
A^\ast A&A^\ast\\
A&I_m+AA^\ast
\end{bmatrix}}
=
\begin{bmatrix}V\\ &U\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma^2&\Sigma&0\\ \Sigma&I_n+\Sigma^2&0\\ 0&0&I_{m-n}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}V^\ast\\ &U^\ast\end{bmatrix}
$$
and hence
$$
\color{red}{\begin{bmatrix}
A^\ast A&A^\ast\\
A&I_m+AA^\ast
\end{bmatrix}}^{-1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}V\\ &U\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma^{-2}+\Sigma^{-4}&-\Sigma^{-3}&0\\ -\Sigma^{-3}&\Sigma^{-2}&0\\ 0&0&I_{m-n}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}V^\ast\\ &U^\ast\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer! The Schur complement approach makes a lot of sense. As for the SVD, how do we know that the matrix multiplication achieves that matrix (and consequently, what the inverse of the 3x3 block matrix is)?

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble making sure the dimensions here are fine. As I'm interpreting this, don't $\Sigma_{m\times m}$ and $0_{(m-n)\times n}$ have a different # of columns?

Comment: @potionboy I don't understand what your first question means. As for the second question, there was a typo. $\Sigma$ should be an $n\times n$ invertible diagonal matrix.

Comment: @potionboy Huh? No, Some authors use the notation $\Sigma$ to denote the rectangular diagonal matrix in the SVD (so that it is $m\times n$), but the $\Sigma^2$ in my answer means $\Sigma_{n\times n}^2$, which is still $n\times n$. I simply dropped the dimension subscript.

Comment: Oh, sorry that makes more sense. (I realized this and deleted the comment when multiplying through $A^*A$.) Thanks again!